# I'm getting a java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 0). error

Tags: java

```
the first is linked to newTown.Index.main(Index.java:20)
```

new AddQuestionView();
System.out.println("adding a question.");

```
the second is linked to  AddQuestionView.java:37)

if(qdao.addQuestion(newQuestion)) {   
        System.out.println(qdao.findIndex()+1+"is added");
        }
```

the third is linked to (QuestionDAO.java:64)

```
    public boolean addQuestion(AddQuestionDTO question) {
        
        try {
            String sql = "insert into question (questionNum,question,answer,level,author)"+
                    "values(?,?,?,?,?)";
            
        
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1,findIndex());
            ps.setString(2, question.question);
            ps.setString(3, question.answer);
            ps.setInt(4, question.level);
            ps.setString(5, question.author);
        
            return ps.executeUpdate() ==1;


and the below are the rest of the errors.
```

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 0).
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1358)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1714)

```
I have 5 parameters in my statement I just can't get which index the error is reffering to.

I checked everything just in case i have a typo. there wasn't any.

can anyone help me out?

thanks.
```

Comment: Not sure, if relevant, but your statement lacks a "space" between ",author)" and "values(".

Comment: Double check your stack trace; I suspect the issue is in `findIndex()`.